# How to avoid setting an useState in an useEffect to trigger infinite re-renders?

Tags: react-hooks

I am new of react, and I understand that there are ways to stop infinite re-renders, but I am not clear how to do it. My objective is to on load page to render only ONCE a change of values in my page if some values exist, and because of that I want to change the useState on where I am storing this data.

I am not clear on how differently I could approach the problem and solve it.

```
useEffect(() => {
        const addOrRemoveEquipment = (itemID, action) => {
            if (itemID && action) {
                if (action === "add") {
                    setEquipmentState([...equipmentState, itemID]);
                } else if (action === "remove") {
                    setEquipmentState((current) =>
                        current.filter((item) => {
                            return item !== itemID[0];
                        })
                    );
                }
            }
        };

        const addOrRemoveItem = (val) => {
            if (val instanceof Array) {
                addOrRemoveEquipment(val[1], "add");
                addOrRemoveEquipment(val[0], "remove");
            }
        };

        addOrRemoveItem([myPlace.remove, myPlace.add]);

        return () => {
            addOrRemoveItem([myPlace.remove, myPlace.add]);
        };
    }, [myPlace.remove, myPlace.add, equipmentState, setEquipmentState]);
```

I was expecting to just change the useState, but it looks like useEffect go crazy when paired with setting an useState inside.

Any suggestions? I read many solutions, I tried, but I am not expert enough to get it right.

Comment: Remove `equipmentState` from the dependencies array and change `setEquipmentState([...equipmentState, itemID]);` to `setEquipmentState(previousEquipmentState => [...previousEquipmentState, itemID]);`

Comment: you are using the useEffect hook to update the equipmentState value based on the myPlace.add and myPlace.remove values. One way to prevent infinite re-renders is to specify these values as dependencies in the useEffect hook's second argument. This will ensure that the useEffect hook only runs when these values change.

Comment: @vighnesh153 would you mind to explain me what is "previousNameState"? and how this works?

Comment: @RaushanKumar I am not sure that I understand what is hook's second argument.

Comment: You should check this out: [Functional state updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)